# Pub/Sub and consumer aware publishing. Stop producing when nobody is subscribed

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to find a messaging system that supports the following use case.

1. Producer registers topic namespace
2. client subscribes to topic
3. first client triggers notification on producer to start producing
4. new client with subscription to the same topic receives data (potentially conflated, similar to hot/cold observables in RX world)
5. When the last client goes away, unsubscribe or crash, notify the producer to stop producing to said topic

I am aware that according to the [pub/sub pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) A producer is defined to be blissfully unaware of the existence of consumers, meaning that my use-case simply does not fit the pub/sub paradigm.

So far I have looked into Kafka, Redis, NATS.io and Amazon SQS, but without much success. I've been thinking about a few possible ways to solve this, Haven't however found anything that would satisfy my needs yet.

One option that springs to mind, for bullet 2) is to model a [request/reply pattern](https://nats-io.github.io/docs/developer/concepts/reqreply.html) as amongs others detailed on the NATS page to have the producer listen to clients. A client would then publish a 'subscribe' message into the system that the producer would pick up on a wildcard subscription. This however leaves one big problem, which is unsubscribing. Assuming the consumer stops as it should, publishing an unsubscribe message just like the subscribe would work. But in the case of a crash or similar this won't work.

I'd be grateful for any ideas, references or architectural patterns/best practices that satisfy the above.

I've been doing quite a bit of research over the past week but haven't come across any satisfying Q&A or articles. Either I'm approaching it entirely wrong, or there just doesn't seem to be much out there which would surprise me as to me, this appears to be a fairly common scenario that applies to many domains.

thanks in advance
Chris

//edit

An actual simple use-case that I have at hand is stock quote distribution.

- Quotes come from external source
- subscribe to stock A quotes from external system when the first end-user looks at stock  A
- Stop receiving quotes for stock A from external system when no more end-users look at said stock

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ has internal events you can use with the [Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html). Event such as `consumer.created` or `consumer.deleted` could be use to trigger some actions at your server level: for example, checking the remaining number of consumers using RabbitMQ [Management API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and takes action such as closing a topic, based on your use cases.

Comment: I believe this is closer to what I'm looking for than what I've seen so far. I had come across this before but dismissed it as a "monitoring" thing rather than something I'd use to drive business logic. Do you have any experience running/using this approach in production and at scale?

Comment: Our own experience is that the management API is ok to do some basic operations from time to time, but if you use it intensively, it begins to lag a lot. But I guess it should depend a lot on your actual usage. Difficult for me to be more precise in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any messaging consumer present based publishing in mind. Got ever worst because you'll need kind of heartbeat mechanism to handle consumer crashes.

So here are my two cents, not sue if you're looking for an out of the box solution, but if not, you could wrap your application around a zookeeper cluster to handle all your use cases. 
Simply use watchers on ephemeral nodes to check when you have no more consumers ( including crashes) and put some watcher around a 'consumers' path to be advertised when you get consumers.

Consumers side, you would have to register your zk node ID whenever you start it.
It's not so complicated to do, and zk is not the only solution for this, you might use other consensus techs as well.

A start for zookeeper :
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html

( strongly advise to use curator api, which handle lot of recipes in a smooth way)

Yannick

Comment: Yeah, Ideally it would be an out of the box solution where I don't have to do the subscription management/refcounting myself. But thanks, I'll have a look at the Zookeeper API and see what I could build on top of it. Never thought of using it for more than simply a requirement for kafka :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you haven't specified your use business use case that you try to solve with such requirements. From the sound of it you want not the pub/sub system, but an orchestration one.

I would recommend checking out the [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that is capable of supporting your listed requirements and many more orchestration use cases.

Here is a strawman design that satisfies your requirements:

- Any new subscriber sends an event to a workflow with a *TopicName* as a *workflowID* to subscribe. If workflow with given ID doesn't exist it is automatically started.
- Any subscribe sends another signal to unsubscribe.
- When no subscribers are left workflow exits.
- Publisher sends an event to the workflow to deliver to subscribers.
- Workflow delivers the event to the subscribers using an activity.
- If workflow with given *TopicName* doesn't run the publish event to it is going to fail.

Cadence offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Distributed CRON support

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll take a look when I get some spare time. Also adding a use-case into the original question

Comment: Looking a the use case I would use Cadence for the subscription management, but pas quote streams directly through in memory streams or external system like Kafka.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I was thinking about doing. Feels quite heavy weight to use cadence for this from what I've read about it so far, but will spike it over the weekend and see how it goes. 

Ideally I'd like to find something more integrated, kinda like managed distributed reactive streams. Gonna keep looking a bit but appears that I'll just have to write something myself